# Expressing "cuteness" through website design

Tags: website-design

(I apologise if this is off topic or too non-specific)

I'm designing myself a personal blog site, and I'd like to make the design "cute". The only cute design elements I can think of (curly fonts, light colors, sparkles, etc) seem to be things looked down upon in today's web design that have been left in the past (and with good reason, for at least some of those things.)

But this leaves me with a problem - how can I express cuteness in a website design without it being garish?

Comment: what have you researched? where did you look for inspiration? what other sites would you consider "cute"? Perhaps you could [edit] your question to add some of these details. "Cute" is a vague concept, different for each person, thus making your question difficult to answer objectively without more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for just a comment, so here I go.

This question is subjective and probably will be closed as it is, but what I find more subjective is

> seem to be things looked down upon in today's web design

There are millions and millions of websites, there is not a monopoly on trends, there are no firms like in fashion where they mark a trend.

If you want and NEED to use curly fonts, light colors, sparkles, etc, please DO. If you want and need to use a cute character make it.

There are some trends, yes, "flat style" was a style that could be adapted to cute or to grudge characters, gradients can be applied to either, 3D the same. You need to separate the elements that are needed with the style they have, and how you manage them together.

I am assuming you actually know how to make a good website, or making it look good: Spacing, proportion, rhythm, etc. You also need to balance visuals and information. So use what you need or want.